# MySQL 1366 incorrect string value: importing unicode characters into MySQL

Tags: mysql

There are several posts on issues with importing unicode characters into MySQL and none of the answers work for me. I will try to post every single detail of the problem as much as I can so that anyone can reproduce this problem. In short I am importing data from Sybase where we have nvarchar support and the characters can be from any language and I am trying to find a universal character set in MySQL that can accommodate anything. I am using utf8mb4 character set and it does NOT work for me.

Here is the error i am getting

[image]

My Server variable configuration

[image]

My schema

```
create DATABASE testdb CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
create table testdb.Tmp1 
 (  DesignName varchar(255) character set utf8mb4 null,  
    CreationDate datetime null)CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I am importing data using MySQL Load command and here is the load command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\tmp.txt'
INTO TABLE testdb.tmp1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
( @DesignName,
  @CreationDate
)
SET DesignName=nullif(@DesignName,''),
    CreationDate = nullif( STR_TO_DATE(@CreationDate,'%M %d %Y %h:%i:%s:%f%p'), "0000-00-00 00:00:00");
```

And here is my test data

```
"Bandpass, Sallen Key, Linear Phase 0.5°","Sep 13 2013  1:11:49:000AM"
"Lowpass, Sallen Key, Linear Phase 0.05°","Jan  4 2014 10:54:58:000PM"
```